# Can I configure VSCode Typescript build task to copy (and update if needed) all non-typescript files from source to dist folder when I build it?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have two folders in my project, src where I want to write all of my code and dist where I want to have a ready to run program once I build all the typescript files, right now after building it looks like this:

[Screenshot of the current project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM2gP.png)

Ideally I want my build task to make sure that the dist folder is a 1:1 copy of the src folder with all .ts files replaced with newly built .js files and to update all other files like .html if I change them in the src folder when I build typescript.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a pretty common case, yet there's no "officially-recommended" way to do it. (Here's a related GitHub issue: [ms/TS#30835](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835).)

You can solve this using a couple of npm packages to help with filesystem manipulation, and some npm scripts to define the behavior you want:

### Packages

First, install these packages:

- [`rimraf`](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) (deletes files)
- [`copyfiles`](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/copyfiles) (copies files)

```
npm install copyfiles rimraf
```

### npm scripts

Then, write a few npm scripts in your `package.json` to combine all of the behavior you want:

`package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf ./dist",
    "build": "npm run compile && npm run copy-assets",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "copy-assets": "copyfiles --all --up 1 --exclude \"./**/*.{ts,tsx}\" \"./src/**/*\" ./dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
  ...
}
```

Script explanations:

- `prebuild`: (This is a [`pre`-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts), and runs before the `build` script) simply deletes the `dist` directory and its contents before the `build` script runs
- `build`: Runs other scripts: first the `compile` script, then (if it was successful) the `copy-assets` script
- `compile`: Runs `tsc` to compile your TypeScript project files according to your `tsconfig.json` (presumably, based on your screenshot, you have configured `compilerOptions.outDir` to `"dist"`)
- `copy-assets`: Copies all files/folders from `src` to `dist` (excluding files ending in `.ts` and `.tsx`). I'll explain this one further, part by part:

  - `copyfiles`: runs the command
  - `--all`: enables copying of all files (including dotfiles)
  - `--up 1`: by default, the target directory `src` will be copied to the destination directory `dist`: instead, this moves all files up one level: everything that would have been copied to `dist/src/` is copied directly into `dist/`
  - `--exclude "./**/*.{ts,tsx}"`: a glob pattern to exclude all files that end in `.ts` and `.tsx`
  - `"./src/**/*"`: a glob pattern for the target: copy all files in `src` recursively
  - `./dist`: the destination directory for the copied files

### Use

Once you've installed those two packages and added the npm scripts, all you need to do is run the `build` script to compile your TypeScript project and copy all the asset files to `dist`:

```
npm run build
```

example:

```
./src
├── index.html
├── script.ts
├── script2.ts
├── subdir
│   ├── Component.tsx
│   └── data.json
└── texture.png

./dist
├── index.html
├── script.js
├── script2.js
├── subdir
│   ├── Component.js
│   └── data.json
└── texture.png
```

**Done!**